# Saving changes for a remote file

Tags: aptana

I am making changes to my file in aptana studio and save my changes. But when I do that, I am getting the following error? Why is that?

Here's the error:

Failed to save the remote file due to exception "Opening File Failed".  Would you like to save the file locally instead?

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Possibly a bad connection or lack of privileges? Are you able to upload files to the remote directory you are trying to save to?

Comment: yes I am. My friend has the same privileges as I do but he can save the changes. I tried to close and reopen aptana studio multiple times, refresh the file, but all that did not help.

Comment: It is possible permissions are different for the particular file you are working on. Is he able to save that one?

Comment: You should be able to see the permissions for the file by right clicking on it in your FTP window or the Remote File Explorer and choosing 'Properties'. So sick of this 5 minute editing rule, btw.

Comment: I will see in to that, Thanks fir the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a file permissions issue.

Make sure your remote server has right permissions.

```
chown -R YOURUSER:YOURGROUP .
```

It's confused because you can open to read it, but then it fails to save with the annoying dialog to save it locally.